# React doesn't read styles from external package

Tags: reactjs, sass, styles

I want to add a photo swiper to my website and I sticked to react-id-swiper. In the documentation it says to import the styles like this:

```
import 'swiper/swiper.scss'
```

and this is my component, pretty straight forward:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';
  import 'swiper/swiper.scss'


  const SimpleSwiper = () => (
    <Swiper>
      <div>Slide 1</div>
      <div>Slide 2</div>
      <div>Slide 3</div>
      <div>Slide 4</div>
      <div>Slide 5</div>
    </Swiper>
  )
   
  export default SimpleSwiper;
```

I did like this, no error, sign that the *.scss file is found, but the no style is applied.
Can anyone tell me why? I looked everywhere, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: If you go on your node modules --> swiper, do you have that scss file in there?

Comment: No, but shouldn't it give an error, like "module not found" ? if it couldn't find the file ? @ale917k

Comment: You are not importing a specific module, but rather the entire file. I guess it'd be nice if it was triggering an error like "imported file not found", but it does not as you don't actually interact with that file (e.g. import modules from it)